# Get different values with one row in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with the following structure (the table shows the change in values ​​over time).

```
ERBS        EUtranCellFDD       PUCCH           PUSCH           Time
__________________________________________________________________________
KO770_4G    KO770L3             0.003851851852  0.032111111111  1622627524
KO770_4G    KO770L3             0.003851851852  0.032111111111  1622623942
KO770_4G    KO770L3             0.003851851852  0.032111111111  1622620348
KO770_4G    KO770L3             100.0           100.0           1622628688
KO770_4G    KO770L3             100.0           100.0           1622631781
KO770_4G    KO770L3             0.011518518519  0.011518518519  1622633365
KO770_4G    KO770L3             100.0           100.0           1622633771
KO770_4G    KO770L3             100.0           100.0           1622633972
KO770_4G    KO770L3             100.0           100.0           1622710689
KO770_4G    KO770L3             98.0            100.0           1622717818
```

I am trying to output a table with the following conditions:

- 1 - **"EUtranCellFDD"** - repetitions are grouped and excluded (I'm
  trying to use them as id),
- 2 - if the values ​​"PUCCH" and "PUSCH"  >= 5
- 3 - **"DegradationTimeStart"** - the time should show the beginning of
  the change "PUCCH" of the last segment (7th record).
- 4 - the values ​​"PUCCH" and "PUSCH" should be shown from the last
  record.(10 line)

Here's what I really want to end up with:

***KO770L3  | 2021-06-02T15:39:32Z | 98.00  | 100.00***

Where the second column is the time the "PUCCH" value was last changed (degradated from 0.011518518519 to 100).

At the moment my code looks like this (maybe my approach is not correct):

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON ("EUtranCellFDD") "EUtranCellFDD",
  to_timestamp("Time")::timestamp AS "DegradationTimeStart",
  "PUCCH","PUSCH"
FROM lte_interference
WHERE
  "PUCCH" >= 5 or "PUSCH" >= 5 
ORDER BY "EUtranCellFDD", "DegradationTimeStart" desc
```

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data as text not image.

Comment: @Serg I have changed the photo for text, but did not understand how else to change the question?

Comment: What is the relevance of `ERBS`? It plays no part n your query and seems irrelevant (its values are constant). Please curate your data to remove all irrelevant columns/rows.

Answer (score 0):

Shows the last row in a group, finds the last degradation time. Degradation condition == (previous row PUCCH <=5 and current PUCCH >5). Change it as needed

```
select  ERBS, EUtranCellFDD,  PUCCH,  PUSCH,
   (select Time
     from (
       select Time,
          case when lag(PUCCH) over(order by Time) <= 5 and PUCCH > 5 then 1 else 0 end degradeflag
       from tbl t1
       where t1.ERBS = t.ERBS and t1.EUtranCellFDD = t.EUtranCellFDD) t2
     where degradeflag = 1 
     order by Time desc
     limit 1       
     )  DegradationTimeStart
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by ERBS, EUtranCellFDD order by time desc) rn
  from tbl) t
where (PUCCH >= 5 or PUSCH >= 5)
  and rn=1
order by ERBS, EUtranCellFDD, Time ;
```